# kill nodes (started with .launch file) properly in Qt, how?

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS Community,

i'm currently developing a `Qt C++ GUI` for a custom made robotic arm.

I have a `QPushButton` that starts a `.launch` file (that launches multiple nodes, i.e., the gazebo, robot spawner, controller spawner, move_group, etc.). The terminal output is printed in a `QPlainTextEdit`. This mechanism works well and is coded as follows.

```
    m_process=new QProcess;
    connect(m_process, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(onBytesAvailable()));
    connect(m_process, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),this,SLOT(onProcessFinished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
    m_process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    m_process->start(roslaunch robot5s_gazebo robot5s_bringup_moveit2.launch);
    bool started=m_process->waitForStarted();
    Q_ASSERT(started);
```

My problem is that **i don't know how to kill successfully** the aforementioned process, ie., to perform basically `CTRL+C`.

If i call `m_process->kill()` i got in my `onProcessFinished` SLOT that the kill was successful: `Process finished, exit code:9     status: 1`, however the nodes are still running, the `rosnode list` gives

```
/gazebo
/gazebo_gui
/joint_controller_spawner
/move_group
/robot5s_controller_spawner
/robot_state_publisher
/rosout
```

**So i want to ask, how to perform the** `CTRL+C` **mechanism for the launched nodes in Qt C++ environment?**

Remark: (Even tho i don't want to kill all the nodes, just the ones that were launched)
I also tried to create another `QProcess` that performes `rosnode kill -a`, but that also did not do the killing successfully, since gazebo kept running.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324076/kill-nodes-(started-with-.launch-file)-properly-in-qt,-how?/) by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2019-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of killing the roslaunch process directly you want to send a SIGINT message to it so that it will shutdown in as if ctrl+c had been pressed in the terminal. There are many ways to go about this, the simplest being to execute a shell command using QProcess the same way you've have started roslaunch in the first place.

```
kill -SIGINT processPIDHere
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-05-27**:
Thanks for the quick answer. This does the job:

```
QProcess* kill_process = new QProcess;

    QString str = "kill -SIGINT " + QString::number(m_process->processId());
    qDebug() << str;
    kill_process->start(str);

    bool started=kill_process->waitForStarted();
    qDebug()<<"Process started:"<<started<<kill_process->errorString();
    Q_ASSERT(started);
```

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-05-27**:
Are you recording the stdout of the roslaunch process? It could be useful to see how it's reacting to the SIGINT and if it is continuing to execute for long enough to kill all the spawned nodes. The only thing I can think is that for some reason the roslaunch process is being killed before it has time shut down all the nodes it's started.

**Comment by [akosodry](https://answers.ros.org/users/35610/akosodry/) on 2019-05-27**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd  IT works, just it takes time. In my case it took 15-20 sec to kill all the nodes!

Thanks you very much again!

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-05-27**:
Great, glad you got it working.